# Slow rsync Transfer Speed over Wi-Fi on OpenWRT

Tags: linux, macos, rsync, openwrt, throughput

I have a USB HDD successfully mounted on my Linksys WRT1900ACS (OpenWRT installed). Laptop is a macbook (MacOS).

Both router and Mac have `rsync` 3.1.3 installed.
File system on USB HDD is ext4.

When copying over media files to the USB HDD with Wi-Fi, I get transfer speeds of 5.5 Megabits per second. When transferring files by ethernet I get 80 Megabits per second.

Wi-Fi connection seems fine. When I download from the internet, I get 40 Megabits per second download speed. So I don't think there is an issue with the Wi-Fi connection itself.

This is the `rsync` command that I used, for both the Wi-Fi and ethernet transfers:

```
rsync --rsync-path=/usr/bin/rsync -r --progress --ignore-existing ~/Mydir root@192.168.1.1:/my/path
```

`Top` results:

```
Mem: 72420K used, 439528K free, 624K shrd, 5560K buff, 19192K cached
CPU:   2% usr   1% sys   0% nic  98% idle   0% io   0% irq   0% sirq
Load average: 0.88 0.60 0.50 2/78 19136
```

UPDATE

I have connected my mac to the USB HDD with SMB. I did a file transfer via the GUI, over Wi-Fi, and it sent 6.2 Gigabytes in 6 minutes. So I can do what I want, but it's still a curiosity as to why the rsync command transfers files so slow. Would like the option to do file transfers by terminal as well as the GUI

Comment: You may not realise that scp and rsync are using the same [ssh] protocol. When you are doing this, what is the load like on the router? (If you run uptime or top it should give an indication)

Comment: Are you running the most up-to-date firmware ([19.07-rc1](https://downloads.openwrt.org/releases/19.07.0-rc1/targets/mvebu/cortexa9/), or if compiling your own, switch to the `openwrt-19.07` branch)?  If not, update and see if the issue still exists.  Have you searched the [OpenWrt forum](https://forum.openwrt.org/) or created a thread on there regarding this issue (that's going to be your best bet for troubleshooting and getting this resolved)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the exact same issue right now and my transfer speed is even slower. I get only about 2MB/s. As you say, this is likely not because of low WiFi transfer speed. However, [davidgo's](https://superuser.com/questions/1479155/slow-rsync-transfer-speed-over-wi-fi-on-openwrt#comment2229777_1479155) comment makes a lot of sense to me. The router has only very limited memory and CPU capacity. Using rsync puts a lot of toll on the router. In my case I get this load:
`Load average: 1.41 1.44 1.21 2/54 8804` which is quite a lot. So I think it is more a problem of the processing power of the router hardware than it is a issue of the WiFi speed.

Since I guess a lot of overhead is produces by rsync using ssh, I'm thinking that it might be faster using something like nfs or samba. Then, you could mount the remote folder locally and copy the files in there. I'll be trying this and see if it improves things and come back to you.

/e:
I didn't have any luck with nfs. Speed was about the same. Still, you might want to check out [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112287/copy-files-without-encryption-ssh-in-local-network). There are some ideas about switching to 
weaker ciphers for the encryption. That might take some load off your CPU, if that is really the issue.

/e²: 
Another thing you might want to do, is to find out how well your router performs ssl encryption operations. I've taken the idea for a  benchmark from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/cf2c32/raspberry_pi_4_4gb_openvpn_performance_tested/) and applied to my TP-Link 1043ND:

```
root@OpenWrt:/tmp# openvpn --genkey --secret secret
root@OpenWrt:/tmp# time openvpn --test-crypto --secret secret --verb 0 --tun-mtu 20000 --cipher aes-256-cbc
Tue Jan 28 22:19:22 2020 disabling NCP mode (--ncp-disable) because not in P2MP client or server mode
real    2m 19.64s
user    2m 16.82s
sys 0m 1.26s
```

3200 / 139.64 =~ 22,9 Mbit/s
139.64 because we look at 2m and 19.64s.
For my router this is close to what I observe. 
However, you have a pretty decent router. I'd expect way higher values for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I ended up using Samba for file transfers, the the speed is exceptional. As I only have a small network, that does it for my needs. But I may explore some of the options in the thread you linked, if I feel bored.